# Exporting state variable from App.jsx to Login.jsx

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a "isLoggedin" variable in my App.js file. I want to change the value of this from false to true in my login.jsx component if the user logs in and then conditionally render the dashboard.

This is my App.js:

```
import React from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'; 
import './App.css';
import Login from './pages/Login/login.pages'
import Dashboard from './pages/Dashboard/dashboard.pages'
import Products from './pages/Products/products.pages'
import Register from './pages/Register/register.pages'
import NavBar from './components/navbar-top/navbar-top.component'
import Test from './components/test.component'

class App extends React.Component {
  
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state ={
      isLoggedin: false
    }
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div className="App">
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/" component={Login} exact/>
            <Route path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
            <Route path="/products" component={Products}/>
            <Route path="/register" component={Register}/>
            <Route path="/navbar" component={NavBar}/>
            <Route path="/test" component={Test}/>
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
      
    );
  }
  
}

export default App;
```

and this is my Login.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import './login.styles.css'
import { ReactComponent as Logo } from '../../assets/Logo.svg'
import axios from 'axios';


export default class Login extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super();
    this.state = {
      email: '',
      password: '',

    }
  }
  changeHandler = event => {
    const name = event.target.name;
    const value = event.target.value;

    this.setState({
      [name]: value
    });
  }

  submitHandler = event => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const user = {
      email: this.state.email,
      password: this.state.password
    };

    axios.post(`http://18.134.134.44:9000/api/employee/login`, user)
      .then(res => {
        if (res.status === 200) {
          this.props.isLoggedin = true;
          console.log(this.props.isLoggedin)
        } else {
          console.log(this.props.isLoggedin)
        }
      })
  }



  render() {
    return (
      <div className="register-container">
        <Logo className="logo" />
        <div className="register-line"></div>
        <form className="login-box" onSubmit={this.submitHandler}>
          <input type="email"
            name="email"
            className="input"
            placeholder="Work email"
            required
            value={this.state.email.value}
            onChange={this.changeHandler}

          />
          <input type="password"
            name="password"
            className="input"
            placeholder="Password"
            required
            value={this.state.password.value}
            onChange={this.changeHandler}
          />

          <input className="button" type="submit" value="LOGIN" />

          <p className="text"> Don't have an account? <a className="register" href="/register">Register</a> </p>
          <a className="register" href="/">Forgot Password</a>
          <p className="text"> {this.props.isLoggedin} </p>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

how can I import "isLoggedin" from app.js to login.jsx, update it and return to App.js to conditionally render the dashboard?

Comment: You can pass props to the component with the following syntax: `<Route path="/" component={() => <Login propName={value} />} />` (e.g. `<Route path="/" component={() => <Login isLoggedin={this.state.isLoggedin} />} />`). You will have to pass both the current login status and a callback to update it.

Comment: unable to update it in Login.jsx as it is a read-only property

Comment: Instead of writing `this.props.isLoggedin = true;` do something like `this.props.handleLogin(true);` and in App.tsx handle this callback to set state of the `isLoggedin`

Comment: @HusnainMehmood, as I mentioned in my previous comment (maybe in a too concise way), you have to move the create a function to update the state in the App component and pass it to the Login one as a prop, so that it can be invoked and executed when the user logs in. It is what I meant when I wrote that you will have to pass a callback too as a prop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to use a third part npm pacakge for state management like Mobx, Redux etc. You can also do this by using Context provided by React.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to store the state externally to the two components so you can adhere to the waterfall data flow approach in React.

This means, in your App.jsx you'll want to add:

```
  const setLoginStatus = (status)=> {
     this.setState({
        loginStatus: status
     });
  }
```

And then pass the state and new function through to your login page with:

```
<Route path="/" path="/" component={() => <Login setLoginStatus={setLoginStatus} loginStatus={isLoggedIn} />} />/>
```

And then in your login you will now have the ability to set the login status that is passed through props via the new `setLoginStatus` function and the `loginStatus` boolean prop as well such as:

```
    axios.post(`http://18.134.134.44:9000/api/employee/login`, user)
      .then(res => {
        if (res.status === 200) {
          this.props.setLoginStatus(true);
          console.log(this.props.loginStatus)
        } else {
          console.log(this.props.loginStatus)
        }
      })
```

Comment: the status comes in undefined when it is logged in the console

Comment: In my response I've used `loginStatus` instead of `isLoggedIn`, have you tried logging all the props to your console to see if you've used an incorrect variable?